# Twitter API sending me "incomplete" statuses

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

*Hey everyone !*

I have weird problem with the Twitter API(I am using Tweepy), when i use `statuses = api.search('pokemon')` 
and then try to print everything with

`for status in statuses:
    if not status.truncated:
        print(status.text)
        print('\n----------------------')`

it sometimes prints weird incomplete statuses with '…' character at the end. And as you can see, they aren't truncated if they get to be printed

Examples:

`RT @CodeNamePizza: Open my first pack ever of the new Forbidden Light Pokemon Set and get the Energy Recycler Secret Rare https://t.co…`

`RT @michaelsenbay: Pokemon GOをやる私「ピカチュウ捕まえた」
我が子「ママ、そのピカチュウにもパパとママがいるよ」
私「お……おう」
我が子「今頃、ピカチュウのパパとママは、そのピカチュウを探しているよ」
私「お……う」
我が子「だから、ライチュウに…`

An other interesting fact:
Every status with that '…' is 140 chars long

*Hoping you can help me,
Thanks !*

Comment: search for "extended tweet"

Comment: Uhm i changed `statuses = api.search('pokemon')` to `statuses = api.search('pokemon', tweet_mode = 'extended')` and i'm printing status.full_text, there still are the '...' chars. Please help

Comment: That should work. Maybe there is a problem with the python library you are using.

Comment: @Jonas I finally found that tweets which were retweeted are never complete, so you have to use status.retweeted_status instead